# Can Google Apps Script handle HTTP DELETE requests?

Tags: http, google-apps-script, routes, request, http-delete

It handles `GET` and `POST` requests just fine, via the respective doGet() & doPost() request handler functions. But what about `DELETE` requests? Is there some kind of implementation of a doDelete() function? My particular use case requires that I can send and receive a response from a `DELETE` request, in addition to `POST` and `GET`.

Comment: There's no doDelete() that I know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web there is no `doDelete` or something similar, only `doPost` and `doGet`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)) DELETE request works fine.

This is how I use it in my project

```js
const params = {
    "method": "DELETE",
    "headers": this.getAuthHeader(),
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
};
const responseString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(this.getBaseUrl() + url, params);
if (responseString.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    return JSON.parse(responseString);
}
```